# Scala : Cant run gcloud compute ssh

Tags: scala, hive, gcloud, spark-shell, gcloud-compute

I am trying to run a hive query using gcloud compute ssh via scala

First, here is what i tried

```
scala> import sys.process._
scala> val results = Seq("hive", "-e", "show databases;").!!
asd
zxc
qwe
scala>
```

which is good. Now, i want to run the same hive command, but against a GCP cluster. I have gcloud setup on my VM and from the command line, i can easily do

```
$ gcloud compute ssh --zone myZone myNode --internal-ip  -- 'hive -e "show databases;"'
Updating project ssh metadata...⠶Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myProject].
Updating project ssh metadata...done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.2746937995265952194' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    19  100    19    0     0   2982      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3166

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
OK
asd
zxc
qwe
```

Now, I want to run the above using scala. Here is what i tried

```
scala> val results = Seq("gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "--zone", "myZone", "myNode", "--internal-ip", "--", "hive", "-e" ,"show databases").!!
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    19  100    19    0     0   3270      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3800
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
NoViableAltException(-1@[846:1: ddlStatement : ( createDatabaseStatement | switchDatabaseStatement | dropDatabaseStatement | createTableStatement | dropTableStatement | truncateTableStatement | alterStatement | descStatement | showStatement | metastoreCheck | createViewStatement | createMaterializedViewStatement | dropViewStatement | dropMaterializedViewStatement | createFunctionStatement | createMacroStatement | createIndexStatement | dropIndexStatement | dropFunctionStatement | reloadFunctionStatement | dropMacroStatement | analyzeStatement | lockStatement | unlockStatement | lockDatabase | unlockDatabase | createRoleStatement | dropRoleStatement | ( grantPrivileges )=> grantPrivileges | ( revokePrivileges )=> revokePrivileges | showGrants | showRoleGrants | showRolePrincipals | showRoles | grantRole | revokeRole | setRole | showCurrentRole | abortTransactionStatement );])
    at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:158)
    at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.ddlStatement(HiveParser.java:3757)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2382)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:4 cannot recognize input near 'show' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in ddl statement
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 64
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
  ... 50 elided

scala>
```

why am i getting this error ? I also tried

```
scala> val results = Seq("gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "--zone", "myZone", "myNode", "--internal-ip", "--", "hive", "-e" ,"show databases;").!!
```

but got the same error. Then i tried

```
scala> val results = Seq("gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "--zone", "myZone", "myNode", "--internal-ip", "--", "'hive -e \"show databases;\"'").!!
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    19  100    19    0     0   3245      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3800
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
bash: hive -e "show databases;": command not found
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 127
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:132)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:102)
  ... 50 elided
```

How can I run the gcloud comput ssh properly using scala ?

Comment: IDK but I don't think you need the single quotes in your last example. You're trying to pass the string `hive -e "show databases;"`. For fun, I would use triple quotes in Scala: `"""hive -e "show databases;""""` to avoid backslash. Single quotes in your good command line are processed by bash.

Comment: that worked! the triple quotes worked :)

Comment: @som-snytt Could you post what you said as an answer so that the post author can accept it as an answer? This will make it more visible to the community

Comment: Wow, it worked? I have terrible quote karma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the single quotes in your last example. You're trying to pass the string:

```
hive -e "show databases;"
```

For fun, I would use triple quotes in Scala:

```
"""hive -e "show databases;""""
```

to avoid backslash. Single quotes in your good command line are processed by bash.

This is what worked in bash:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh --zone myZone myNode --internal-ip  -- 'hive -e "show databases;"'
```

`scala.sys.process` got some basic parsing at some point. There is a space in this file name that must be quoted. Amazingly, it seems to do shell-style quotes:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.13.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.3).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import scala.sys.process._
import scala.sys.process._

scala> "ls -l /tmp/skypeforlinux Crashes".!!
ls: cannot access '/tmp/skypeforlinux': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'Crashes': No such file or directory
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 2
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:155)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 28 elided

scala> """ls -l "/tmp/skypeforlinux Crashes"""".!!
res1: String =
"total 0
"

scala> """ls -l '/tmp/skypeforlinux Crashes'""".!!
res2: String =
"total 0
"

scala> """ls -l /tmp/skypeforlin'ux Cr'ashes""".!!
res3: String =
"total 0
"

scala> """echo 'hive -e "show databases;"'""".!!
res4: String =
"hive -e "show databases;"
"
```

The double quotes around `"my house"` are part of the file name:

```
scala> """ls '/tmp/"my house"'""".!!
res5: String =
"/tmp/"my house"
"
```

I guess that code is where I learned how shell-style quotes work, though I never have a chance to use that knowledge. Except for this answer, so thanks for the opportunity.